# how to create basic chat app using messagekit and firebase (Realtime Database)?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, messagekit

The problem im facing is how can i recognize the sender and reciever of the message ? tried so hard but didn't find any delegate method from which i can separate message and show like chat , right now my msgs are showing like this

[image: My Screen looks like this]

the second problem is ,  I want my msgs on the right side but its appearing on the left side of the screen

**My Firebase Schema for Chat**

[image: schema]

will be very really thankful if someone could guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to implement

```swift
    func currentSender() -> SenderType
```

in your `MessagesDataSource` to return a struct or class that conforms to `SenderType` with some ID that identifies the sender in your backend. In your `MessageType` object, you also need to store the current sender of that message as your `SenderType` object. (I'm guessing the `sender` variable on your Firebase message schema would work for that?)

MessageKit will take care of laying out your cells on the correct side based on the `senderId` of `message.sender` vs `currentSender()`, you don't need to do anything explicit other than ensuring the Sender object has the correct senderId for each message, and return the current sender in your MessagesDataSource.

Comment: thank alot buddy , there is one or two things more which i need to figure out , would you please help me regarding that ? first is Im not getting that navigation bar on the top when i scroll up its getting into safe area as you can see in the first image